# Problems while managing this python exception: Can't continue with the next iteration/element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, exception

I have a script which extract text from an xml document, the problem is that there is an empty xml file, therefore I managed as follows:

```
documents_dir = ['../file_1.xml', .....,'../file_N.xml']

try:
    for f in p.imap_unordered(extract_txt, documents_dir):
        print('completed file:', f)
except ShellError:
    pass
```

The thing is that instead of continuing with the next file, the flow of the for loop is stopped. How can I simply continue?, note that I tried to use the `pass`. However, it is not working.

**Update**

Alternatively, I tried to:

```
try:
    p.imap_unordered(extract_txt, documents_dir)
except ShellError:
    pass
```

Nevertheless, it doesn't worked.

Comment: Thanks for the help @AChampion The `for` line is causing the error. Which other logic can I use for such purpose? (multithreaded map over a list of file paths)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store off the iterator so you can resume iteration:

```
documents_dir = ['../file_1.xml', .....,'../file_N.xml']

results = p.imap_unordered(extract_txt, documents_dir)
while True:
    try:
        for f in results:
            print('completed file:', f)
        break
    except ShellError:
        continue
```

Each time you hit a `ShellError`, it continues the infinite loop to try to restart the `for` loop over the same iterator with the next value; as soon as the loop ends naturally, it `break`s the infinite loop. If some other unrecognized exception is raised, the loop is exited as the exception bubbles.